# A loop that shows all posts on the single post page

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

after someone clicks on one of my posts I want him to see this post and below every other post I have made. I have tried to copy and paste different loops. Why does a second default loop on single.php only show the very same post that is already there?

thanks.This is the single.php:
fourth edit:

```
<div id="primary" class="site-content">
    <div id="content" role="main">

        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>

            <?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>

        <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

  <?php wp_reset_postdata(); // reset the post data so we can run another query ?>
  <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

  <?php 
  // The Second Query
   $the_query = new WP_Query();

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ):
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ):
        $the_query->the_post(); ?>

    <div <?php post_class(); ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
        <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>

        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); // Restore original Post ?>
    </div><!-- #content -->

</div><!-- #primary -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just copy and paste the loop again and expect it to show you something different. You need to first do [wp_reset_postdata()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata). You then need to write a new query, and do a new loop. For example:

```
<?php // First Query ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); // reset the post data so we can run another query ?>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>

<?php 
    // The Second Query
    $the_query = new WP_Query();

    // The Loop
    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ):
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ):
            $the_query->the_post(); ?>

        <div <?php post_class(); ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
            <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div>

        <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); // Restore original Post ?>
```

Read more about writing queries [in the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).

Comment: thanks, could you take a look on my second edit? The page is blank when I click on a post.

Comment: You have syntax errors. You should try copying what I have above in as the second query. I made an edit because I originally had a syntax error as well.

Comment: thanks again, could you check my third edit? So far it only shows one post.

Comment: You need an `<?php endif; ?>` directly after the first `<?php endwhile; ?>`

Comment: Alright,that makes sense, but the page is blank again.

Comment: I can't help you debug your code. You'll want to work on correcting syntax errors where appropriate. Please close up this question, and ask a new one if you run into additional problems.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at this plugin : https://wordpress.org/plugins/yet-another-related-posts-plugin/